# amenability on Banach algebras

Tags: examples-counterexamples

we know that $C_0(G)$ is Banach $M(G)$ bi-module for locally compact group $G$.
I would like to know that is there derivation of $M(G)$ into $C_0(G)$? Or is it inner every derivation of $M(G)$ into $C_0(G)$ ?